# How to autofill formulae in MS Excel such that it skips some lines in the middle?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

My MS-Excel Worksheet has the following formulae...

[image: Img01]

When I copy all cells from `H4:I12`, and paste them in `H13`(excel pastes in range `H13:I21`), I get the following autofill:
`H4` changes to `H13` because it is being pasted into `13th row`.

[image: Img02]

Here the Dark Blue Cells have been autofilled correctly but the ones in light blue have not...

But I need the following autofill changes:
  `H4 to H5`,    `O4 to O5`,    `U4 to U5`  in  `13th, 14th & 15th rows` and similarly
`AB4 to AB5`, `AI4 to AI5`, `AO4 to AO5` in `17th, 18th & 19th rows`

[image: Img03]

I know this is standard Excel Behaviour, but I have a lot of such rows and I don't think I can keep changing row numbers manually... How should I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue copying, I think this is a way

You must manually change the formula in all the light blue cells you have just mentioned H4, H5, H6, I4, I5, I6, ...

`H4= Subgrades!H4` *change to* `=INDIRECT ("Subgrades!H" &(INT((ROW()-ROW($4:$4))/9)+4))`

`H5= Subgrades!O4` *change to* `=INDIRECT ("Subgrades!O" &(INT((ROW()-ROW($4:$4))/9)+4))`

and so on until I10.then you can copy all cells from H4:I12, and paste them in H13, H21,...